# Looping through rows in Nebula Grid

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nebula

I have a Nebula Grid with rows of data in it.

How do I loop through each row to capture data from it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this on my own endeavours to find an answer to my own question. Anyways, looping through a nebulagrids rows (or griditems, as they are called) can be accomplished like this:

```
GridItem[] itemList = grid.getItems();
for(GridItem item:itemList){
    System.out.println(item.getText());
}
```

Depending on the data you want to retrieve from an item you will have to replace item.getText() with something to your own liking.